# Make text box visible based on the item selected in dropdown django, forms

Tags: python, django, forms

My forms.html

```
<fieldset class="task-info">
  {{ form_field(task_form['execution_time']) }}
  {{ form_field(task_form['admin_time']) }}
  {{ form_field(task_form['difficulty']) }}
  {{ form_field(task_form['priority']) }}
</fieldset>
```

My form.py

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
admin_time = forms.CharField(
            help_text=_('Enter If more than 60 minutes.'),
            required=False,
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'fill-width'}))
keywords = (forms.CharField(
            help_text=_('Please use commas to separate your keywords.'),
            required=False,
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'medium-field'})))

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['instance']:
        initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
        initial['keywords'] = kwargs['instance'].keywords_list
        kwargs['initial'] = initial
    super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def _process_keywords(self, creator):
    if 'keywords' in self.changed_data:
        kw = [k.strip() for k in self.cleaned_data['keywords'].split(',')]
        self.instance.replace_keywords(kw, creator)

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(TaskForm, self).clean()
    start_date = cleaned_data.get('start_date')
    end_date = cleaned_data.get('end_date')
    if start_date and end_date:
        if start_date >= end_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("'End date' must be after 'Start date'"))
    return cleaned_data

def save(self, creator, *args, **kwargs):
    self.instance.creator = creator
    super(TaskForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if kwargs.get('commit', True):
        self._process_keywords(creator)
    return self.instance

class Media:
    css = {
        'all': ('css/admin_ace.css',)
    }

class Meta:
    model = Task
    fields = ('name', 'short_description', 'execution_time', 'difficulty',
              'priority', 'repeatable', 'team', 'project', 'type', 'start_date',
              'end_date', 'why_this_matters', 'prerequisites', 'instructions',
              'is_draft', 'is_invalid')
    widgets = {
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 100, 'class': 'fill-width'}),
        'short_description': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 100, 'class': 'fill-width'}),
        'instructions': AceWidget(mode='markdown', theme='textmate', width='800px',
                                  height='300px', wordwrap=True,
                                  attrs={'class': 'fill-width'}),
        'start_date': CalendarInput,
        'end_date': CalendarInput,
        'why_this_matters': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 2, 'class': 'fill-width'}),
        'prerequisites': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 4, 'class': 'fill-width'}),
    }
```

Models.py there's a class 
    class Task(CachedModel, CreatedModifiedModel, CreatedByModel): In it execution_time is defined

```
execution_time = models.IntegerField(
    choices=((i, i) for i in (15, 30, 45, 60)),
    blank=False,
    default=30,
    verbose_name='estimated time'
)
```

What I want to achieve is there should be one more choice after 60, that can be 'Add new value',when this option is taken then only the admin_time textbox should appear.

Any one on how to achieve this ? We need to use JavaScript I assume

Comment: You'll be determining this via client-side interaction...so you're correct with your JavaScript assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Put the input box in a div.

```
.text-box-div {
    display:none;
}
```

Add this JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

        $('.text-box-div').hide(); 
        $('.add-new-value').show(); 

    $('.add-new-value').click(function(){ 
    $('.text-box-div').slideToggle(); 

    }); 
});
```